# Horrific Windows Server 2012 R2 & Visual Studio Crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-server-2012-r2

So, I have a question someone here may know the answer to... I am trying to debug and trace through some C# code on a remote Windows Server 2012 R2 with Visual Studio installed.  I am using a Debugger.Launch() call to hook into the program and Visual Studio properly launches and shows me the proper break point.

However, once I try to step-in, step-over, or even just resume execution, the entire server crashes and reboots.  There is absolutely nothing being recorded to explain what the problem is in the event log other than the usual 'previous reboot was unexpected' message.  This problem happens regardless of whether I try to debug the application as a console application or as a Windows service.

The server is being accessed via Remote Desktop and the source code files are located on my local drive (e.g. "\tsclient\X\path\to\source.cs").  I've already scoured the web for a few days trying to find anything and everything that might help but I have not found anything that helps.  I have even tried to make sure that VS is excluded from DEP and that did not change the end result either.

This is happening with Visual Studio 2012, 2013, and 2015 (all with the latest updates applied).  In addition, all Windows Updates have been applied to the server.  The strangest part is that this was all working as of about a month or two ago when I needed to debug a different application.

So gurus of stackoverflow, does anyone know a) what would cause this and b) how to fix it?

eG

EDIT: Fixed path example which didn't like angle brackets. =\

Comment: Obvious and simple answer, but have you scanned for virus/malware?

Comment: Yep! No virii or malwares present.  This even happens on a brand new install (even thought maybe something in the OS got hosed so I reinstalled it).

Comment: Does it happen if you debug locally with files, Visual Studio and app running on the same server?

Comment: I'll give it a try and report back the answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Sounds like a driver problem, did you check whether the reboot is being caused by a BSOD?

Comment: Agree with @CollinDauphinee I think its a network driver problem

Comment: I do not think it was a network driver issue, and debugging from local copies of the source did not make a difference. :(  I've worked around the problem so I'm just going to close this issue.  Good luck to anyone who encounters the same problem.